# Find Polynomials with Integer Coefficients with Particular Roots

Tags: polynomials, radicals

Is there any simple way to find a polynomial with integer coefficients so that ($x=\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}$) is one of its roots? I know one way is to get rid of all the square roots in the equation to be left with rational numbers, but is there any other *simple* way?

Comment: "I know one way": should we guess what your way is ?

Comment: And yet another failure of "trusted" users to [search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%24%2C%20minimal%20polynomial&p=1).

Comment: Mind you, I didn't downvote the question. Newbies get some slack. The answerers... I don't know. My finger is twitching. OTOH this isn't calculus or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this simple?
$$x=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$$
$$x^2=2+3+2\sqrt2\sqrt3$$
$$x^2-5=2\sqrt6$$
$$(x^2-5)^2=24$$
$$x^4-10x^2+1=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Square it $$x^2 =2+2\sqrt{6}+3$$ so $$(x^2-5)^2 = 4\cdot 6$$
so $$ p(x) = x^4 -10x^2+1$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $x_0=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$. If we take another root to be $x_1=\sqrt2-\sqrt3$, by Vieta's formulas we get the equation

$$x^2-2\sqrt2x-1=0$$ and we can get rid of the square root by writing

$$(x^2-1)^2=8x^2.$$

---

Alternatively,

$$x-\sqrt2=\sqrt3\to x^2-2\sqrt2x+2=3\to(x^2-1)^2=8x^2.$$